# Keep "no data" tiles as "no data" w/ proximity (raster distance) operation

Tags: qgis, gdal, proximity

Working in QGIS 2.8.1 Wien.

I have a raster file with three classes:

"No data" for tiles outside of the country of interest's bounds
"0" for tiles that correspond to roads
"1" for all other tiles.

I want to use proximity (raster distance) to create a new raster layer of distance to roads for all tiles... but want to maintain the "no data" tiles as "no data".

However, when I run proximity, it ignores any calls to the "No data = " option and assigns distance values to all "no data" tiles. I can't type any string input into the "No data = " option, and am unsure of how to keep my "no data" cells.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*No Data* values are not stored as "No Data" inside raster files but like any other value. The difference is that the dataset then has a flag which tells QGIS which value to ignore.

You need to find out what value represents *No Data* in your raster and enter that value into the No Data field in the proximity analysis settings.

You can find the value either with:

- `Properties --> Metadata --> Properties: No Data Value`

or

- `Raster --> Misc. --> Information`